# Problems using _GLIBCXX_DEBUG with yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, stdvector, yaml-cpp

I find it convenient to use the flag _GLIBCXX_DEBUG when compiling c++ with gcc in debug builds since they enable range checking for std::vector and the like. However, when I use yaml-cpp to parse yaml files, I get a strange error when this flag is enabled. It works as expected without the flag.

I constructed an example as simple as possible to demonstrate the issue.
I have the following main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main()
{
    YAML::Node node = YAML::LoadFile("test.yml");
    std::cout << "value of x = " << node["x"] << "\n";
}
```

and this super simple yaml file called test.yml:

```
x: 1
```

From here I first built and ran it like this

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lyaml-cpp -g 
./main
```

and got the expected output:

`value of x = 1`

If I then added the _GLIBCXX_DEBUG flag, i.e compiled and ran it like this:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lyaml-cpp -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
./main
```

I get the ouput:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

If I run it in a debugger and view the call stack I get a bit more insight.
It is this access `node["x"]` that causes the segfault, and the error occurs in this member function in the file impl.h:

```
template <typename Key>
inline Node Node::operator[](const Key& key) {
  EnsureNodeExists();
  detail::node& value = m_pNode->get(key, m_pMemory);
  return Node(value, m_pMemory);
}
```

I'm leaning towards that this is a bug in the yaml-cpp library, but perhaps it's just me who is using it wrongly.. I never know. I tried to remedy the problem by using skipping the _GLIBCXX_DEBUG option for the source files that uses yaml-cpp, but this caused some other issues. Unless I figure this out I guess I just have to make without the _GLIBCXX_DEBUG flag :(

Comment: That flag has the potential to radically alter the size and layout of standard library datastructures. You cannot mix and match code that has been compiled with this. Build yaml-cpp with that flag enabled as well and link against that.

Comment: I guess I then need two versions of yaml-cpp installed if I want to use it both with and without _GLIBCXX_DEBUG. Any advice on how to accomplish this without getting any conflicts with naming and so on?

Comment: A common approach is to mark the debug libraries with a "d" suffix. For example "libyamlcpp-d.so". Alternatively, you can statically link the debug version of yamlcpp in your debug builds and use the dynamic release library elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure my solution is the best, but I did the following. I built two static versions by specifying cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -g" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install_debug for the debug build and cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install_default for the other build. and when I for instance want to link the default version in a project, I specify  -I/path/to/install_default/include -L/path/to/install_default/lib -lyaml-cpp. This seems to work at least

Comment: Great! I suggest you write this as a self answer so others can find and learn from it.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include an answer. Instead, add the answer below, under the "Your Answer" heading. Otherwise, it makes it difficult for people viewing the page to determine which is the question and which is the solution.

Comment: you might prefer _GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS, which provides many of the checks of _DEBUG without the ABI incompatibility

Answer (score 1):

I Learned that this issue was caused by the fact that yaml-cpp was not installed with the _GLIBCXX_DEBUG flag enabled. This info is actually in the readme on github  https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp

I ended up installing two versions so that I can use it with and without _GLIBCXX_DEBUG.

These were installed the following way:
I followed the installation procedure given here: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp, but I created two build diretories, build_debug and build_default. For the debug I used the following cmake command:
`cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -g" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install_debug`, the first option specifying that I want to build with -g and -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG flags and the latter option specifying a non-standard installation path.

Now to link with it in a code project, I used the following with g++:
`g++ <other options> -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG I/path/to/install_debug/include -L/path/to/install_debug/lib -lyaml-cpp`

To install the default version, I used the following cmake command:
`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install_default`, and the following command to link:
`g++ <other options> I/path/to/install_default/include -L/path/to/install_default/lib -lyaml-cpp`

This way two static libraries are built separately, and there are no conflicts.